# Invalid use of this in member function

Tags: c++

I have method in my class how return reference to an object, but I don't know how can I access to my attribut in this method.

```
Particule& update(double timestamp)
{
    this->vx += timestamp;
}
```

`vx` is an attribut to my Object `Particule`. But if I try to access `vx` with `this` I have an error why ? I thought this would work.

My class definition:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

class Particule{

    public:

    double rx, ry;      //position
    double vx, vy;      //velocity
    double fx, fy;      //force
    double mass;        //mass

    Particule ();
    Particule(double rx, double ry, double vx, double vy, double fx, double fy, double mass);

    Particule& update(double timestamp);

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, Particule const& p)
    {
        return str <<
        "rx : " << p.rx <<
        " ry : " << p.ry <<
        " vx : " << p.vx <<
        " vy : " << p.vy <<
        " mass : " << p.mass << '\n';
    }
};
```

And I don't know how can access to my object in my method update. I call this methode by `object.update(timestamp);`

Comment: Is this code within a class definition?

Comment: Error is : `Invalid use 'this' outside of a non static member function`

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]

Comment: You have declared `update` outside of its class definition.  Either move the method into the class definition or change it to "your_class_name"::update

Answer (score 4):

If definition is outside the class, you have to do something like:

```
Particule& Particule::update(double timestamp)
{
    this->vx += timestamp;
    return *this;
}
```